# Boost.Python - How to return by reference?

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I'm using Boost.Python to create Python modules from C++ classes. And I ran into a problem with references.

Condider the following case where I have a class Foo with overloaded get methods that can either return by value or reference.

Specifying that the return by value should be used was easy once I typedefed a signature. But I think it should be possible return a reference as well by using a  `return_value_policy`. However, using what seemed appropriate ([doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/v2/reference_existing_object.html)); `return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>` did not seem to work.

Have I misunderstood what it does?

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(float x) { _x = x; }
    float& get() { return _x; }
    float  get() const { return _x; }
private:
    float _x;
};

// Wrapper code
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    typedef float (Foo::*get_by_value)() const;
    typedef float& (Foo::*get_by_ref)();

    class_<Foo>("Foo", init<float>())
        .def("get", get_by_value(&Foo::get))
        .def("get_ref", get_by_ref(&Foo::get),
            return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>())//Doesn't work
        ;
}
```

Note: I know it could be dangerous to reference existing object without life-time managing.

**Update:**
It looks like it works for objects but not basic data types.
Take this revised example:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(float x) { _x = x; }
    float& get() { return _x; }
    float  get() const { return _x; }
    void set( float f ){ _x = f;}
    Foo& self(){return *this;}
private:
    float _x;
};

// Wrapper code
using namespace boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module)
{
    typedef float (Foo::*get_by_value)() const;

    class_<Foo>("Foo", init<float>())
        .def("get", get_by_value(&Foo::get))
        .def("get_self", &Foo::self,
            return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>())
        .def("set", &Foo::set);
        ;
}
```

Which in a test gave the expected result:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo(123)
>>> foo1.get()
123.0
>>> foo2 = foo1.get_self()
>>> foo2.set(1)
>>> foo1.get()
1.0
>>> id(foo1) == id(foo2)
False
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python, there's the concept of *immutable types*. An immutable type can't have its value changed. Examples of built-in immutable types are int, float and str.

Having said that, you can't do what you want with `boost::python`, because Python itself does not allow you to change the value of the float returned by the function.

Your second example shows one solution, another would be to create thin-wrappers and exposing that:

```
void Foo_set_x(Foo& self, float value) {
    self.get() = value;
}

class_<Foo>("Foo", init<float>())
    ...
    .def("set", &Foo_set_x);
;
```

Which is a better solution than having to change the original C++ class.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want [return internal reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/python/doc/v2/return_internal_reference.html) instead.  I have used it before to do something similar.

Edit: [Latest doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/models_of_callpolicies.html#function_invocation_and_creation.models_of_callpolicies.boost_python_return_internal_ref)

Comment: It's the same deal. It works on objects but not basic data types.

Comment: the link to documentation is for version 1.38, which is very old as of this comment (1.61 is current)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Boost.Python, so I may misunderstand the question, in which case this is completely unhelpful. But here goes:

In Python you can't choose between returning by reference or by value, the distinction doesn't make sense in Python. I find it's easiest to think of it as everything being handled by reference.

You just have objects, and you have names for those objects. So

```
foo = "ryiuy"
```

Creates the string object "ryiuy" and then lets you refer to that string object with the name "foo". So in Python, when you get passed something, you get passed that object. There is no "values" as such, so you can't pass the value. But then again, it's also a valid viewpoint that there aren't references either, just objects and their names.

So the answer is, I guess, is that when you get a reference in C, you need to pass a reference to the object that reference references into Python. And when you get a value in C, you need to pass a reference to the object that you create from that value into Python.

Comment: Yeah, I know everything is references in Python. When I create a python method with Boost.Python that returns "by value" it returns a copy of that type. What I want to do is to *not* copy, but instead create a reference to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the c++ object is being copied? You will get a new python object each time but which references the same c++ object. How are you determining that the object has been copied?

Comment: It does not compile when I try to use references. 
As to how to determine if it's references or copies is easy. Create two references to what you think is the same object, modify one and see if the changes appear in the other. (using id(obj) would not work).

Comment: Yeah, was asking to check you weren't using id(). Whats the compile error?

Comment: It's a boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE, which indicates that something I do is either unsupported or illegal. I just don't know what.

Comment: I updated my example with reference to Foo and not float, which works.